# Действительно ли меняется SID, когда изменяется уровень целостности?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, безопасность

Я изменяю уровень целостности у процесса. Значит ли это, что должен измениться и SID?

У меня есть структура:

```
struct info
{
     wchar_t name_PID[100]; // the name of process
     //maybe DWORD not unsigned
    unsigned num_PID; // the id of the proc
     char* path;// the way like C://
     char par_name[100]; // the name of parent
    unsigned num_par_PID;// the id of the parent
     char ownerName[256]="\0"; // host/adm/elv
     char* SID;
    unsigned x_bit;
    char DEP[4];
    char ASLR[4];
    char DLL[30][1000];
    PCSTR integrityString; // тут лежит уровень low,medium,high,system
};
```

Информация хранится в stl list,  то есть в каждой ноде у я могу обращаться к этим полям. На момент выполнения следующей функции все эти поля заполнены.

Я действую максимально в лоб:

0.Пробегаю по всем нодам листа и ищу нужный мне процесс для проверки своих рассуждений

1.Открываю какой-нибудь текстовый документ, в Process Explorer проверяю его PID(process ID).  Его pid вы можете видеть в этой проверке `if (it->num_PID == 32356)`

2.[Тут](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) написано, что ,например,будет SID: S-1-16-0, при ненадежном уровне целостности. По этой причине я меняю SID ведь я тоже изменяю уровни целостности.
Хотя я уверен,что это должно произойти автоматически у процесса, но ,как убедимся в дальнейшем, Process Explorer покажет, что SID вообще не изменился, а уровень целостности - да.

3.Дальше работает сам код

```
void change_integraty(list <info>& gqlist)
{
    list <info> ::iterator it;
    for (it = gqlist.begin(); it != gqlist.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->num_PID == 10712)
        {
            it->integrityString = "Untrusted";

            PSID sid;
            const char *sidStr;
            if (!strcmp(it->integrityString, "Untrusted"))
            {

                sidStr = "S-1-16-0";
            }
            else
            {
                if (!strcmp(it->integrityString, "Low"))
                {
                    sidStr = "S-1-16-4096";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!strcmp(it->integrityString, "Medium"))
                    {
                        sidStr = "S-1-16-8192";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!strcmp(it->integrityString, "High"))
                        {
                            sidStr = "S-1-16-12288";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!strcmp(it->integrityString, "System"))
                            {
                                sidStr = "S-1-16-16384";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sidStr = "S-1-16-20480";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            ConvertStringSidToSidA((LPSTR)sidStr, &sid);

            DWORD returnLength = 0;
            //HANDLE hToken;
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, it->num_PID);// по номеру процесса получаю его дескриптор
            //HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, it->num_PID);
            PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL mandatoryLabel = NULL;
            if (hProcess == NULL)
            {
                continue;
            }
            OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT, &hProcess);// создаю токен 
            //OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT, &hToken);
            GetTokenInformation(hProcess, TokenIntegrityLevel, NULL, 0, &returnLength);// 902 // c NULL возвращает длину буффера
            mandatoryLabel = (PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL)malloc(returnLength);
            GetTokenInformation(hProcess, TokenIntegrityLevel, mandatoryLabel, returnLength, &returnLength); //беру инфу о токене
            mandatoryLabel->Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
            mandatoryLabel->Label.Sid = sid;
            sprintf(it->SID, "%s", (char*)sid);
            SetTokenInformation(hProcess, TokenIntegrityLevel, mandatoryLabel, returnLength);// вношу изменения в целостность
            CloseHandle(hProcess);

            //CloseHandle(hToken);
        }


        //the_username_sid(gqlist);
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядел SID до изменений в целостности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот такой был уровень целостности до изменений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и ожидалось уровень целостности изменился после отработки программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот только SID остался таким же:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако на английском stackoverflow меня уверяли в обратном - изменю токен процесса, поменяется SID. Вот этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026195/does-sid-changes-if-we-change-the-integrity-level/58026379#58026379)

Значит изменение уровня целостности никак не влияет на SID? Зачем же тогда об этом написали в [майкрософт](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) ?
Действительно ли  должен меняется SID, когда изменяется уровень целостности?

Comment: @VTT, почему , я же ясно вижу,что integrity level изменился

Comment: Какая версия Windows?

Comment: @MrBin, windows 10

Comment: Я не нашел упоминание Windows 10. Так что лучше все заново перечитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids). Исходя из описание [SID](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/secgloss/s-gly), я предполагаю, что уровень целостности зависит от SID только при НЕ УСТАНОВКИ вручную уровня целостности. Например: запускаем exe от авторизованного пользователя - уровень целостности будет high. Но вы также можете изменить его на low или medium (Про system не уверен), что НЕ повлияет на SID.